# Using strcmp in a while condition to break the loop

Tags: c

I need to write a program where the program needs to loop and get input from the user. In order to break the loop, the user will need to type exit on the keyboard.
The following is my code:

```
int main()
{
    char input[100];
    char terminate[100]="$exit";
    //if input does not equals to terminate keep asking user for input
    while(strcmp(input, terminate)!=0)
    {
        printf("$");
        fgets(input,100,stdin);
    }//otherwise, exit the program
}
```

I tried testing the code above but it keeps on looping even after typing the word exit. Your assistance is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: What input are you expecting after the symbol '$'?

Answer (score 2):

`fgets` will read the EOL character which will be included in the final string.

You may use `strncmp` to just use the characters from "terminate": `strncmp(input, terminate, strlen(terminate)`.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I truly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

There are *two* (and possibly three) problems in your code as you show it:

1. The first, which is very serious, is that you use `input` before it's initialized. That means the contents of the array is *indeterminate* (and could be seen as "random" or "garbage"). That will very likely lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when you use it in `strcmp` because it's not a proper null-terminated string.
2. The second problem is that [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) adds the ending newline in the buffer, so unless you remove it or add a newline in the string you compare with the strings will never be equal.

   You can easily remove the newline from the input string by using the [`strcspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn) function:

   ```
   input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = 0;
   ```

---

The possible third problem is that you seem to be adding the prompt `$` in the string you compare. Unless the user actually writes the `$` in the input given, it will not be part of the input.

You also don't need to use as many characters for the `terminate` array. Instead let the compiler decide the proper amount:

```
char terminate[] = "exit";  // The size of the array will be 5, including null-terminator
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Here is my solution:

```
while(strncmp(input, terminate,4)!=0)
    {
        printf("$");
        fgets(input,100,stdin);
    }
```

use strncmp instead of strcmp.

Comment: That doesn't solve all the problems, and will allow the user to input `$exi` to exit.